# Data help on major employers near private universities in U.S

Tags: data.gov

I’m looking to find out which universities are near the regional or national headquarters of employers.

This is for a project to improve hiring opportunities for university graduates.

Would you please direct me to someone in our Department of Education who’s an authority on this?

Comment: what have you done to find this data?